# Screenshot with transparent background

Tags: java, swing, awt, bufferedimage

I created a program with several JLabels. Each of them shows a png file with transparent background. With this code I can overlay them and take a screenshot, but the panel is also taken.
How can I do to keep the background transparent?

**BuildGUI.java**

```
        JLabel labelFirst = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img/first.png"));
        labelFirst.setBounds(10, 10, 250, 190);
        panelScreenshot.add(labelFirst);
        
        JLabel labelSecond = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img/second.png"));
        labelSecond.setBounds(10, 10, 250, 190);
        panelScreenshot.add(labelSecond);
        
        JLabel labelThird = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("img/third.png"));
        labelThird.setBounds(10, 10, 250, 190);
        panelScreenshot.add(labelThird);

        
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==btnSave) {
            classSave salvataggio = new classSave();
            salvataggio.classSave(panelScreenshot);
        }
    }
```

**classSave.java**

```
    public void classSave(Component component) {
        Rectangle rect = component.getBounds();

        try {
            String dirName = ("Save/");
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());
            String fileName = timeStamp + "." + "png";
            File dir = new File (dirName);
            boolean dirCreated = dir.mkdir();

            if(dirCreated) {
                System.out.println("The directory has been created.");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("The directory already exists.");
            }
            BufferedImage captureImage =
                new BufferedImage(rect.width, rect.height,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            component.paint(captureImage.getGraphics());
            ImageIO.write(captureImage, "png" , new File(dir, fileName));
            System.out.println("The file was saved!");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `component.paint(captureImage.getGraphics());` I don't think you should call method `paint` directly. Refer to [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) lesson in Oracle's Java tutorials. Maybe method [createScreenCapture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture(java.awt.Rectangle)), in class `java.awt.Robot`, will give you better results?

Comment: *...but the panel is also taken.* - try making the panel transparent.

Comment: @Abra I solved it with panelScreenshot.setOpaque(false);
Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Bishop *I solved it with panelScreenshot.setOpaque(false);* - your welcome.